# Поиск нескольких ближайших значений в массиве

Tags: java

Возникла задача из огромного количества данных хранящихся в массиве найти несколько чисел наиболее близких к переданному значению. Нашёл такой вариант.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187352/find-closest-value-in-an-ordererd-list Его можно адаптировать если для каждого прохода удалять из массива найденное наиболее близкое значение, но это слишком долго. как оптимизировать что бы поиск шёл за минимальное количество проходов?

```
public int closest(int of, List<Integer> in) {
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int closest = of;

for (int v : in) {
    final int diff = Math.abs(v - of);

    if (diff < min) {
        min = diff;
        closest = v;
    }
}

return closest;
}
```

Comment: Можно же за один проход решить. И этот код как раз один проход и реализует. В чем сложность его изменить для сохранения нескольких значений?

Comment: @IntFloat не смог придумать как сделать это ещё и красиво

Comment: А у вас список отсортирован, или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Делайте вот что:

1. Заведите отсортированный по расстоянию список наиболее близких элементов, в начале пустой. Пусть это будет результирующий список.
2. Пробегайтесь по данному списку
3. Каждый элемент данного списка сравнивайте со элементами результирующего списка. Найдите последний индекс элемента, который ближе к данному. Если это последний индекс списка, и список полон, ничего не делайте, иначе добавьте текущий элемент в список, и если список переполнится, удалите последний элемент.
4. В конце вы получите искомый список.

Код:

```
public static List<Integer> closest_n(int of, List<Integer> in, int n) {
    List<Integer> closest = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> diffs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int v : in) {
        final int diff = Math.abs(v - of);

        int index = Collections.binarySearch(diffs, diff);
        if (index < 0) {
            index = -(index + 1);
        }

        if (index >= n) {
            continue;
        }

        closest.add(index, v);
        diffs.add(index, diff);

        if (closest.size() > n) {
            closest.remove(n);
            diffs.remove(n);
        }
    }

    return closest;
}
```